# Process builder with multiple actions

Tags: process-builder, developer

Currently I have the task of creating a process builder that creates a billing record.

On update/edit if [create billing statement] is checked then it runs.

- action 1: create billing record
- action 2: uncheck the [create billing statement] checkbox
- action 3: update the related fee records to lookup    to the new
  created billing record

When is it good or bad practice to have multiple actions in one process builder?
What does this process builder fall under (good/bad practice)?

Comment: The only issue I see is if you're dealing with large numbers of records (i.e. this Create Billing Statement checkbox is marked on 200+ records all in one transaction).  You can test this yourself and keep the developer console open to see the debug logs - there you'll see how much time is being spent in the PBs and if you hit any governor limits